# Creating a structure (datastructure) in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, data-structures

I'm really beginner in this field...

My question is: how can I create a structure in shell script (or bash, I'm not sure about the difference)

In  C for example we can simply:

```
struct name
{
    __u8 x;
    __u8 y;
    signed short z;
    float t;
    float u;
};
```

Is it possible to create something similar to this in shell?

Why?

I need to copy some values to a /proc file..but I need to be sure about they are 12 bytes, and the order of them, because I want to assign them to the previous structure which is inside a linux kernel module

Thank you for any useful answer or hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest a better tool for the job, Python? It's installed on most Linux systems, and you can write scripts with it, just put the appropriate shebang at the top:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

Or,

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

Then use [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module to pack values into binary representation.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys, struct
# Convert first 5 arguments
args = [f(arg) for f,arg in zip([int,int,int,float,float], sys.argv[1:])]
sys.stdout.write(struct.pack('BBhff',*args))
```

Which is equivalent to,

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys, struct
x = int(sys.argv[1])
y = int(sys.argv[2])
z = int(sys.argv[3])
t = float(sys.argv[4])
u = float(sys.argv[5])
sys.stdout.write(struct.pack('BBhff',x,y,z,t,u))
```

And can be invoked as:

```
./script.py 1 2 3 4.0 5.0 > /proc/somefile...
```

**EDIT:** Or read from another file:

```
./script.py `cat args-file` > /proc/somefile...
```

Comment: It seems really a good idea, but the problem that I don't have any idea about Python :( , and my project should be submitted till Monday

so..could you please write the lines with the same variables I used..

because I'm confused about many things in your code. for example: the declaration of variables and list, where should I assign my variables...and many things else

Thank you very much

Comment: @Yacob, I've made it a bit simpler. Does it help?

Comment: yea...It really helps, but I'll ask for one more thing: if I want to assign the values inside the file, or (that's my real task) to take the values from another text file (maybe to read each line and assign it to a specific arg) 
how can I do that?
Thanx again and again

Comment: @Yacob, sure, you can use the shell to read arguments from a file (one per line, or one line, space separated). See edit.

Comment: Very nice, except for the space between `#!` and the interpreter :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo -en` to dump out raw bytes with bash, for example `echo -en "\000\001"` will print out two bytes: 0x00 and 0x01. So you just need to know the specific bytes, encode them as octal values in your shell script, and then `echo -en` them to your proc file. I don't think you'll have much luck trying to convert a bash variable to a four byte float though; if you need to compute the values for your `struct` then bash isn't your best choice. I'd bet that someone around here could come up with a way to do it but that doesn't mean that it is the right thing to do.

Do you have Perl, Ruby, Python, PHP available? They all have a `pack` function for cramming native numbers into byte streams that will match the layout of a C `struct`. With any of those you could do some calculations, `pack` the values into your 12 byte format, and then dump them to your proc file.

Another option would be to write a small C program: include the appropriate header to get the module's `struct`, fill it in, and `fwrite` it to your proc file. This option would be my first choice as the header should take care of getting the padding and whatnot right.

Comment: about the Python stuff I don'e have any idea about it (I'm working on Ubuntu 11.04)...It would be nice if you'll write it for me..because really I don't have time to learn anything in the left  time for my project.


For the second choice, I think it is a very good idea, I'll try it, but maybe I'll ask you about something in it
because programming isn't my field, but I need it inside my project.

Thanks a lot